# Can I safely sell all items marked as treasure in Recettear?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

In Recettear, I've recently found a Very Odd Vase. It sells for around 22 000 gold. This is a great and highly welcomed surprise to me at this early point in the game. However, I find myself being cautious even now as an old man asks me to sell him a treasure item because I don't want to give away my Very Old Vase, in case it ends up being useful later on.

Am I being overly cautious, and is this the same situation as Chantelise, where all treasure can be safely sold? Or is there any reason for me to hold on to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you are safe selling anything and everything you find. Most items are obtainable multiple times, and even the unique ones dropped by bosses will drop again if you go through that dungeon again.

In the case of the Very Odd Vase, that is only dropped from the boss on the 15th floor of Jade Way, and randomly purchasable through customers, making it a bit uncommon. While I'm pretty sure that the vase isn't used for anything important later on in the game, you may want to double check the [Recettear Wiki's Fusion Table](http://recettear.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion) before selling items, as it could be a pain in the neck trying to find these useful items again after you've sold them away.

If you're ever unsure about an item's value, and you aren't still in the middle of the debt-paying phase, you can always keep the item on hand. Apparently each saved game has a [maximum limit of 15,000 items](http://recettear.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Items), so hoard away!

Like you, I have yet to finish the game, so others can feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in assuming that all items are re-obtainable.

Comment: I'll just confirm for you directly - the Very Odd Vase is not used in any fusion. It's also a very common thing for people to sell to you, so it's all in all, a good idea to sell when you have it and people are willing to pay its exorbitant price (for the early game).

Comment: Yes, at this point in the game the Very Odd Vase can make quite the substantial impact on your profits if sold. Make sure your customers can afford it though by raising their heart levels!

Comment: Also, as long as you have owned the item, all recipes with that item are viewable in the fusion list. So feel free to sell treasure items, and if you realize you need one for a recipe, you can hang on to any additional copies you might find.

Comment: Bear in mind, the V.O.V. makes for an /excellent/ customer draw while it's on display due to its high value. So even if it isn't bought for a week, it'll more than earn its keep with the increased number of customers it brings in.